# Python проверка url (не медиа файл)

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть кроулер, который бежит по страничкам определённого домена и вытягивает все ссылки. Данные ссылки не должны быть `.png`, `.pdf`, `.mp4` и т. д. Проверка с помощью длинного `if` не устраивает:

```
if '.png' in url or '.gif' in url or '.jpg' in url or '.jpeg' in url:
    continue
```

Есть ли более быстрые способы проверить ссылки на языке Python 3?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Наиболее быстро будет так:

```
dis_ext = tuple('.png .jpg .pdf .mp4'.split())
if url.endswith(dis_ext):
    continue
```

Comment: Да, действительно.

Answer (score 1):

Выделяете расширение, потом:

```
checkList = [".jpg", ".txt"]
ext = ".jpg"
if (ext in checkList)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ignored_extensions = '.png', '.gif', '.jpg', '.jpeg'
if url.endswith(ignored_extensions):
    continue
```